# Boost managed_shared_memory not working with C's mmap call on freeBSD

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, freebsd, mmap

I am having two processes and they are sharing
shared-memory.

- Process-1 (implemented in c++ and using boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory interface)
- Process-2 (implemented in c and using "she_open" and "mmap" interfaces)

This code was working fine on Linux But When I deployed same code on FreeBSD. Process-2 (C lang based) is keep on throwing error in mmap. Error is "Bad file Descriptor".

Please let me know:

1. Do I need to change the interface while moving from Linux to FreeBSD.
2. Is there any known issue with this design.

Code Snippet:

Process-1(c++):

```
obj = new boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory( boost::interprocess::open_or_create,<shm_name>, <shm_size>); // to create shm
obj->allocate(<data_size>) ; // to write in shm
```

Process-2 (c):

```
int fd = shm_open(<shm_name>,O_RDWR, 0666);
void * startpoint = mmap(NULL, <shm_size>, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); // using the startpoint to read data written by process-1.
```

Boost version:

Boost.1.63.0

Thanks.

Comment: Please print `strerror(errno)` after `shm_open`, to see why fd is bad.

Comment: it's giving "Invalid argument" while creating fd from shm_open call.

Comment: Here you may suspect file-name/path as corrupted parameter in shm_open. But I was using same name on Linux and it was working fine. shm_name is "TestShared_Memory1". I  believe this issue is some how related to shm_location in my freeBSD 10.